# How to append list of dictonary to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, append

How to append list of  dictionaries in python?

I'm trying to create JSON data using python where data is retrieved from MongoDB.
I need to get the JSON data in the below format.
Note: I retrieved all the required data from db.I'm not sure to append that data in the desired JSON format.

**JSON Data:**

```
"System_Details":
{
"System_id":"001",
"Details":[
{
  "name":"Job-Info"
  "job":[
  {
    "category":"1",
    { 
      "eid":"01",
      "role":"associate-1"
    },
    {
      "eid":"02",
      "role":"associate-2"
    },
    { 
      "eid";"03",
      "role":"associate-3"
    }
  },

  {
    "category":"2",
    { 
      "eid":"04",
      "role":"associate-4"
    },
    {
      "eid":"05",
      "role":"associate-5"
    },
    { 
      "eid";"06",
      "role":"associate-6"
    }
  },
   
]
}
]}
```

**My script:**

```
System_Details = {}
System_Details['Details'] = []
job = []
job_dict = {}
System_Details["System_id"]= <SYSTEMID ## which is retrieved from db>
job.append(job_dict)   #job_dict is having above json values which is mentioned inside job list("job":[])
```

Now job = [ ] Contains

```
  "job":[
  {
    "category":"1",
    { 
      "eid":"01",
      "role":"associate-1"
    },
    {
      "eid':"02",
      "role":"associate-2"
    },
    { 
      "eid";"03",
      "role":"associate-3"
    }
  },

  {
    "category":"2",
    { 
      "eid":"04",
      "role":"associate-4"
    },
    {
      "eid':"05",
      "role":"associate-5"
    },
    { 
      "eid";"06",
      "role":"associate-6"
    }
  },
]
```

How can I append this list to System_Details['Details']?

Please note the curly braces inside System_Details ['Details'] while appending.

**In short**

```
"System_Details":
{
  "Details":[
    { 
      ...
      ...
       "job":[
         {
           ...
         },
         {
           ...
         }
      ]
   }
]}
```

How to append "job":[] to "Details":[] ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: the json you posted is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is not clear, answering this based on the given understanding.

```
"System_Details":
{
  "Details":[
    { 
      ...
      ...
       "job":[
         {
           ...
         },
         {
           ...
         }
      ]
   }
]
}
```

So, there are two lists `Details` and `job`. You want to append all the items present in the `job` to appended on `Details` list.

You can append a list to another list by using [extend()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/extend.html) in python.

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> l.extend([3, 4])
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l.extend('foo')
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'f', 'o', 'o']
>>> l.extend((5, 6))
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'f', 'o', 'o', 5, 6]
>>> l.extend({'x': 100, 'y': 200})
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'f', 'o', 'o', 5, 6, 'y', 'x']
```

Please update your question or comment on the answer, if it answers your question.